# .bat fails - where is the problem

Tags: windows, batch-file

What could cause running a batch file to terminate in the middle of running?

Comment: Please provide source code, error messages, anything really...

Answer (score 2):

An `exit` statement will cause a batch file to terminate early.

Answer (score 0):

There exists some immediatly stop errors.
But in your special case, the cause is unknown, like the code.

```
rem error1 - Invalid % Expansion
rem %~

rem error2 - call REM /?
set "switch=/?" 
call rem %%switch%%

rem error3 - stackoverflow
:stack
call :stack

rem error4 - call caret crash only with Vista
set "caret=^"
call echo %%caret%%

rem error5 - Long expansion
rem shows that expansion of % in a line is before the rem ignores the rest of the line
rem The expansion results in a very long line with 10000 characters, the batch stops immediatly
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "longStr=."
for /L %%c in (1,1,13) DO set longStr=!longStr:~0,2500!!longStr:~0,2500!
rem Now we heave a string with 5000 characters, and build a rem line with 2 times 5000 = 10000 characters
rem The next line crashes the batch file
rem tokenOne %longStr% %longStr%
(
    ENDLOCAL
    goto :eof
)

rem error 6 - %%var<LF> error, crashes only sometimes
set critical_content=hello%%~^

echo $
for %%a in (1 ) do (
    for %%x in (4) do (
        rem #%critical_content%#
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

As others mentioned, this is too open-ended to answer effectively.

Nevertheless, you may want to see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1455157/bat-script-only-executes-1-line/1455176#1455176) about needing the `CALL` command to call another batch script and have it return to the call site.